# Python use requests instead of swagger_client API (ESCO API)

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm trying to use the ESCO REST API Docs with python 3.10.6, via requests or an alternative to installing the swagger_client. For what I understand it is not a common method to use anymore.

```
https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/doc/esco_api_doc.html
```

I was building a request in order to retrieve some data tables containing the concept or occupation data (depending on the urls), but I haven't managed to get the data.

The following code contains what I have been trying to do with requests

```
import requests

headers = {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    
    'Referer': 'https://esco.ec.europa.eu/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'dnt': '1',
}

url='https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/occupation?isInScheme=22'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I get a response that is not very convincing, it does not reflect the data on the tables related to the content I'm searching for

```
{'count': 0,
 'language': 'en',
 'concepts': [],
 'offset': 0,
 'total': 0,
 '_links': {'self': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/concept?isInScheme=22'},
  'first': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/concept?isInScheme=22&offset=0&limit=20'},
  'last': {'href': 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/concept?isInScheme=22&offset=-20&limit=20'}},
 '_embedded': {}}
```

Is there a way to get the main concept schemes by using requests library?

```
https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/doc/esco-api-further-doc.html#_questions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been looking at pulling specific data from ESCO using the URI references, the following extracts the requested data (though the requested language preference is ignored).

```
import json, requests, sys

url_root = 'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/'
target_uri = "http://data.europa.eu/esco/occupation/528f90ed-e250-48bd-aacc-ffb7b1de5654" # String | The unique identifier of the requested resource
language = 'en' # String | The default language of the returned response. Overwrites the Accept-Language header. (optional)
acceptLanguage = 'en' # String | The default language of the returned response. Optional and might be overwritten by the language request parameter. (optional)

header = {
    'content_type': 'application/json',
    'charset': 'UTF-8'
}
params = {
    'uri': target_uri,
    'language': language
}

url = url_root + 'occupation'
try:
    # Get occupation
    resp = requests.get(url, headers = header, params = params)
    print(resp.json())
except Exception as e:
    print("request exception:  %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: Do you have (1) a way to get all occupations, (2) a way to get all skills, (3) an example using taxonomy?